# TFVC when getting a changeset for rollback, the files are not automatically checked out

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2015, rollback, tfvc, source-control-explorer

In TFVC when getting a changeset for rollback, the files are not automatically checked out.
The mechanism for this is to use Visual Studio 2015, access Source Control Explorer, History, right-click on a specific change set, and "get this version".

The result is getting the correct version of the files, however, there are no relevant "pending changes".  Worse still, for larger changesets, it may be difficult to discern which files were obtained.  The code is for asp.net, so there can be quite a hodge-podge of different files involved.

A work around I found is to copy and paste the whole file contents into the local file of the same name, but obviously, that is undesirable.

I don't really have any code to show or relevant screenshots as the repository contents are proprietary.

Any ideas?